# Подскажите алгоритм запроса на подсчет количества разных объектов по группам в зависимости от кода и вывод во view по полу

Tags: sql, алгоритм, postgresql

У меня есть 4 таблицы, 3 из которых участвует для связи many-to-many, а четвертая с основными двумя сущностями:

Subject, создается всегда

| id | name | addressId | sex | has_object |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75675 | Anna | 4 | f | false |
| 75677 | Sam | 7 | m | true |
| 75678 | Toma | 3 | f | true |

Object, который, создается вместе с subject, но не обязательный к заполнению

| id | name | addressId | is_fake |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3434 | House | 3 | false |
| 3435 | Parking | 3 | true |
| 3433 | Shop | 6 | false |

sub_obj, промежуточная для связывания таблиц

| id | sub_id | obj_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75678 | 3434 |
| 2 | 75677 | 3433 |
| 3 | 75675 | 3435 |

Address, id которого в двух первых

| id | code | city | country | continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 100 100 | Rome | Italy | Europe |
| 2 | 100 130 234 | Venice | Italy | Europe |
| 3 | 100 200 343 | Paris | France | Europe |
| 4 | 100 200 643 | Brest | France | Europe |
| 5 | 100 200 244 | Nice | France | Europe |
| 6 | 200 340 244 | Brasilia | Brazil | South America |
| 7 | 200 250 244 | Rio de janeiro | Brazil | South America |

Предполагается, что в представление будет присылаться код адреса (либо пустое значение для группировки по континентам, либо код континента для отчета по странах, либо код страны для группировки по городам), и в зависимости от него(в разрезе мира, континента, и страны) будет вычиcлятся сумма субъектов и субъектов по названию адреса по полу
в по странам Европы

| name_area | Count_male subject_total | Count_male subject_with_object | count_object_by_male | Count_female subject_total | Count_female_subject_with_object | count_object_by_female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| France | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

По континентам

| name_area | Count_male subject_total | Count_male subject_with_object | count_object_by_male | Count_female subject_total | Count_female_subject_with_object | count_object_by_female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Europe | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| South America | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Как найти и сгруппировать по странам континента, если известно, что первой цифре страны соответствует первая цифра номера континента (x00000000), которая присылается с бэка, и в дальнейшем можно было произвести подсчет количества obj и subj относительно этой страны

в по странам Европы (входной параметр 100000000)

| name_area | Count_male subject_total | Count_male subject_with_object | count_object_by_male | Count_female subject_total | Count_female_subject_with_object | count_object_by_female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| France | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос? Что хотите сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Связываешь всё в одну плоскую таблицу (где надо - LEFT JOIN), а затем агрегируешь с требуемыми фильтрациями (`COUNT(column) FILTER ( {condition} )`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ Akira под вопросом. Спасибо